# PHP tag within a form opening tag getting error

Tags: php, html

When I'm putting some code within a html a form tag it's not working as it should be.

```
<form action = "update.php?id= <?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
```

The form open tag above is taking the php closing tag as it's closing tag. Why is this happening? It should take the last closing tag as it's closing tag.
The view source is as following:

```
<div class="phpcoding">
<section class="headeroption">
    <h2>PHP CRUD</h2>
</section>
    <section class="maincontent">
UDATE tbl_crud SET Name = 'mister', skill = 'Biscuit', email = 'mistecookie@gmail.com' WHERE id = ' 8'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UDATE tbl_crud SET Name = 'mister', skill = 'Biscuit', email = 'mistec' at line 152
```

Comment: What is the generated html you get? Are yo sure that your php is correctly processed?

Comment: 1. what is the extension of this code file-> `.html` or `.php`? if `.html` then you have to convert it to `.php`. 2 May be because of  unnecessary spaces you have, change it to:- `<form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">`

Comment: I'm assuming from the way you worded your question that you might not be serving this via a PHP webserver. Are you sure it's not being served as pure HTML? Can we see what your browser shows when you "View Source"?

Comment: @u_mulder it's a php file. The only problem is with the tag

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Thanks for your response. it's a php file. I have tried to remove spaces and it still shows the same problem

Comment: It seems what @andrewgu  is said that is correct. Can you share what he asked in his comment? Also what URL you are hitting for this code to run, share that too

Comment: `right syntax to use near 'UDATE` - Right, so where is that code? What you posted does not support the real question here.

Comment: @MasumAbid  please add in your question. reading code inside comment is pretty hectic task.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh the url is: http://localhost/oop_mysqli_crud-template/update.php?id=%208

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Sorry for your problem. I have added it with the question

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Would you please check again? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
<form <?php echo 'action="update.php?id='.$id.'" method="post"'; ?> >
```

or

```
<form <?php echo 'action="update.php?id='.$id.'"'; ?> method="post">
```

Hope it will work for you. :))

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this and it's showing the same problem. The form tag isn't taking the last tag ass it's closing tag rather it's taking the php ending tag

Comment: So it seems that php on your system is not working at all. what tool you are using:- Xampp/Wampp/Lampp/Wamp to execute your php file

Comment: Then there may be some closing tag present in file. May be you have not typed that but that go mistyped. Do a search for that and delete that. Use ctrl+f and do search for it. It happens sometimes with me too. Thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Thanks for your response. I'm working on Xampp. But other things are working fine